# Kafka consumer and a web server simultaneously, thread blocking problem microservice

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka, thread-safety, microservices, kafka-consumer-api

**assumptions:**
There are microservices behind an api-gateway, they communicate through HTTP synchronously. obviously, each one of those microservices is a web server. now I want my microservice to play as a Kafka producer and "consumer" too. more clearly, my microservice produces events and listens to some topics for other events.

**problem:**
It seems traditionally a Kafka consumer use an infinite loop to poll the messages and stay alive (send heart-beats) my process thread is busy by serving host and cant be locked by an infinite loop. is there any way to somehow "listen" to the topic without block the thread just like pulsar listener or rabbit? *I prefer not to separate my web server and consumer-processor due to the technical complexity I have to handle in development*. may I use Kafka streams in this case? Is there something wrong with my assumptions?

Answer (score 1):

You could just put your Consumer in its own Thread.

Assuming Java since you mentioned Kafka Streams, then if you're using Quarkus, Micronaut, Spring-Kafka, Reactor, Vertx, or similar Java web framework that also have Kafka connectors, that's what they do. If you're not using a web framework beyond basic Jersey, you probably should.

Comment: yes pal I'm using Clojure, as I mentioned I prefer not to separate them because of adding the complexity of those tools you mentioned, other tools will be needed, and other considerations like managing a separate service (aka container) and etc. I prefer the consumer(and its process function) and web server in one thread somehow. do Kafka streams block the main thread when you start the topology?

Comment: Kafka Streams is just a layer over the consumer api. The threads are in the background, though, yes. And that "complexity" allows you to instrument your code like adding useful metrics and logs for when things go wrong (you don't need containers)

Comment: yes you are right there is a trade-off and we may lose some of them in case of short of resources, training people, and a completely new dev stack, etc. about containers: If my consumer is totally a separate jar (like my webserver) where should I put it so can I manage it? who would run a new instance if the consumer crashed or something?

Comment: If the consumer JAR is on the classpath, you can just start it from `main` like anything else and use whatever tools your framework has for watching for failed tasks and retrying.

Comment: @Gho containers and standalone jars would need to be monitored the same way - use JMX metric collection. I don't understand what you mean by "where to put it"

Answer (score 0):

Even with Clojure, just abstract the Thread away like https://github.com/gklijs/bkes-demo/blob/main/topology/src/nl/openweb/topology/client.clj or any of the several Clojure clients about now. If you go wild you can use core.async.